# What does $H(\kappa)$ mean?

Tags: set-theory, definition, cardinals

As the typical references (Wikipedia, Mathworld, etc.) don't seem to address this satisfactorily, I figured this would be a good place to put a nice formal definition. Hence:

> I've heard that if $\kappa$ is a strongly inaccessible cardinal, then $H(\kappa)$ (or sometimes $H_\kappa$) equals $V_\kappa$.  What does $H(\kappa)$ mean in this instance and how is it defined?

Comment: @Asaf: Why did you change the (large-cardinals) tag to (cardinals)?  Since $\kappa$ is a strongly inaccessible cardinal, which ZFC can't prove exists, doesn't that meet the criteria for (large-cardinals)?

Comment: $H(\kappa)$ is not reserved for inaccessible cardinals. In fact, when talking about inaccessible cardinals this is the same as talking about $V_\kappa$. On the other hand, $H(\omega_1)$ is used throughout set theory, as well $H(\kappa)$ for other non-large cardinals. Since you *only asked* about the definition I don't see why it should be tagged as [large-cardinals].

Comment: Ah. I've been stuck in large-cardinal land for the past several days. Good catch.

Comment: Large cardinals are fun.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The elements of $H(\kappa)$ are the sets that are *hereditarily of cardinality less than* $\kappa$. If $x\in H(\kappa)$, then $|x|<\kappa$, $|y|<\kappa$ for every $y\in x$, $|z|<\kappa$ whenever there are $x$ and $y$, such that $z\in y\in x$, and so on.

This gives the intuitive idea, but it’s not really a definition. For that it’s easiest to start by defining the *transitive closure* of a set $x$:

$$\operatorname{tr cl}(x)=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}{\bigcup}^n(x)\;,$$

where

$${\bigcup}^n(x)=\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }n=0\\\\
{\bigcup}\left({\bigcup}^{n-1}(x)\right),&\text{if }n>0\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then $$H(\kappa)=\{x:|\operatorname{tr cl}(x)|<\kappa\}\;.$$

(Although it doesn’t have the form required by the axiom schema of comprehension, this definition can be justified by showing that $H(\kappa)\subseteq V_\kappa$ for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$.)

Assuming AC, $H(\kappa)=V_\kappa$ iff either $\kappa=\omega$ or $\kappa$ is a [beth fixed point](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Beth#beth_fixed_point); this is proved in the answer by François G. Dorais to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5543/cardinality-of-h-kappa). (Beth fixed points exist in ZFC.)

Comment: @tomasz: Probably a good idea, yes; done.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I'm new to TeX. Is there a way to add more space between the two rows of your piecewise definition for ${\bigcup}^n(x)$?

Comment: @Travis: Is that better now?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Much easier to read. :-) I was struggling to see what change you made to the TeX, but then I figured out that somehow with SE's dynamic updating, the page had refreshed but view-source was still giving me the old source until I did a manual refresh.

Comment: @Travis: You can also right-click on a formula and select *Show Math As* and then *TeX Commands* from the context menu. (Or click on the time stamp where it says ‘edited 15 mins ago’ to see the revision history, though in general I find that less useful.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks. It was the revision history that showed me my view-source was out of date (even though I opened view-source after SE dynamically refreshed the page).

Comment: To conclude that the transitive closure of a set $x$ that is hereditarily of cardinality $< \kappa$ is of cardinality $< \kappa$, you need to assume that the cardinal $\kappa$ is regular, I think. So your definition of $H(\kappa)$ is only "correct" for regular $\kappa$.

Comment: @Daniel: In fact Ken Kunen defines $H(\kappa)$ to be $\{x:|\operatorname{tr cl}(x)|<\kappa\}$ in his $1980$ book *Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs*.

Comment: @Brian Okay, I accept that. ;)

Comment: It's not true that $H(\kappa)=V_{\kappa}$ iff $\kappa=0$ or strongly inaccessible. $H(\kappa)=V_{\kappa}$ holds whenever $\kappa$ is a [beth fixed point](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Beth#beth_fixed_point), and ZFC proves that beth fixed points exist.

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson: Thanks for catching the error, which I believe I’ve now fixed.

Answer (score 9):

Given an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, by $H(\kappa)$ we denote the family of all sets *hereditarily* of cardinality less than $\kappa$.  Of course, this might beg the question: What do we mean by *hereditarily* of cardinality less than $\kappa$?

Well, in order for $x$ to be hereditarily of cardinality less than $\kappa$ we demand that

- $x$ itself has cardinality less than $\kappa$; and
- every element of $x$ has cardinality less than $\kappa$; and
- every element of every element of $x$ has cardinality less than $\kappa$; and
- $\ldots$

I think you get the picture.  More succinctly, $x \in H(\kappa)$ iff its *transitive closure*, $\mathop{TC}(x)$, has cardinality $< \kappa$.  This set is defined to be either the smallest transitive set including $x$, or, equivalently, to be $\bigcup_{n \in \omega} \bigcup^{(n)} x$ where for each $n \in \omega$ we inductively define $\bigcup^{(n)}x$ by

- $\bigcup^{(0)} x = x$; and
- $\bigcup^{(n+1)} x = \bigcup \left( \bigcup^{(n)} x \right)$.

Comment: To conclude that the transitive closure of a set $x$ that is hereditarily of cardinality $< \kappa$ is of cardinality $< \kappa$, you need to assume that the cardinal $\kappa$ is regular, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I'd leave an alternate version of transitive closure in case readers might find it more intuitive/useful.

The transitive closure of a set $A$ is defined as
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{cl}_0(A)&:=A\\
\operatorname{cl}_{n+1}(A)&:=\bigcup\operatorname{cl}_n(A)\\
\operatorname{cl}(A)&:=\bigcup_{n<\omega}\operatorname{cl}_n(A).\end{align}$$

Note:

- $A=\operatorname{cl}_0(A)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(A)$
- If $A\subseteq B$ and $B$ is transitive then $\operatorname{cl}(A)\subseteq B$