# In $\sf{ZF}$, is every finite set also hereditarily finite?

Tags: set-theory

The following is an excerpt from Wikipedia's [Hereditarily finite set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set) page:

> A recursive definition of well-founded hereditarily finite sets goes as follows:
>
> - *Base case*: The empty set is a hereditarily finite set.
> - *Recursion rule*: If $a_1,...,a_k$ are hereditarily finite, then so is $\{ a_1,...,a_k\}$.
>
> The set of all well-founded hereditarily finite sets is denoted $V_ω$. If we denote $P(S)$ for the power set of $S, \ V_ω$ can also be constructed by first taking the empty set written $V_0$, then $V_1 = P(V_0), V_2 = P(V_1),..., V_k = P(V_k−1),...$ Then
> $\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty V_k = V_\omega$.

Does not any finite set lie in $V_\omega$ ? If not, then can anybody give an example of a finite but not hereditarily finite set?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/186844/8348) and its answers may also be of interest. (This question deals with a more general notion, and using the notations therein the family of hereditarily finite sets would be denoted $H(\omega)$.)

Comment: I now looked at another question [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186844/what-does-h-kappa-mean/186849#186849), and your notation really seem more appropriate. I just used the notation in Wikipedia.

Comment: Yes, the $H(\cdot)$ notation is somewhat more appropriate in general.  The notation used in the "Hereditary finite set" Wikipedia page uses the [von Neumann cumulative hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe). It just so happens that $V_\omega = H(\omega)$, so in the end there is no difference _in this particular instance_. Usually $V_\kappa$ and $H(\kappa)$ will be quite different.

Comment: My question can be treated as "wrong" - I simply did not read correctly the definition. But I *obstinately* incorrectly read it, which means my intuition was wrong and @Rene's short answer corrected my intuition. A justification for such a question is that Frege wondered whether by "ensemble" Cantor meant what we now call "set" or what we now call "transitive set" (I think, I read about this in Fraenkel Bar-Hillel Levy "Foundations of Set Theory").

Answer (score 11):

$$\{\omega\}$$ is finite but not hereditary finite since it contains an infinite set

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that $\omega$ is a set is a consequence of the axiom of infinity, and therefore $\{\omega\}$ is also a set.

Comment: Based on this, probably, my question could be improved by rephrasing its begining like this: "In ZF without axiom of infinity,.... "

Comment: @IoachimDrugus In ZF with the *negation* of infinity, every set is finite, which implies that every set is hereditarily finite (because the elements of a set are sets, which are finite, whose elements are sets, which are finite, etc.). Thus "every finite set is hereditarily finite" is equivalent to the negation of infinity (otherwise $\{\omega\}$ is a counterexample).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Slightly off-topic, I thought one needed to deduce axiom of Empty Set from Replacement on ( x =/= x ) via the assertion at least one set exists (from Infinity itself) in order to show that the standard definition in Infinity is meaningful (otherwise, { } is not proven to actually be a set even though it exists as an element in the set defined in Infinity), though this always seemed a bit circular to me. Plus standard Infinity doesn't directly claim ω exists, it claims an inductive set exists, and ω is defined as the intersection of all inductive sets. Am I misled anywhere?

Comment: @TrixieWolf: Indeed off-topic, and there would be much better places to have this discussion (in the comments) on this website alone. But to answer your question, this is of course very much dependant on how you phrase Infinity (sometimes it is phrased as "$\omega$ exists), but even in its most rudimentary form, it states that there is a set $S$ and that one of the elements of $S$ is the empty set. And therefore the empty set exists. Again, this was asked and discussed in length on the site before.